# Trusted host patterns on drupal

Tags: php, drupal

While working on Docker I Installed Drupal and while trying to finish all my configuration is giving me an error telling me that

"trusted_host_patterns is not configured in the settings.php file".

I went into the settings.php file and uncommented the next line:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
    '^www\.example\.com$',
);
```

Even with that line uncommented it still gives me the same problem.

I would appreciate any help given, I looked for a solution but all the questions are not solved.

Comment: Did you replace the example pattern: `^www\.example\.com$` with one that matches the URL you are using for your Docker container?

Comment: Yes, I did it and still gave me the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in another line with simply **'localhost',** or whatever your docker site hostname is locally.

I actually did this today with my docker site and I created a settings.local.php and at the end of that I have:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  'localhost',
);
```